# Puppet applying catalog either in multiple runs or does't apply completely

Tags: puppet

I have a Win (Server 2012 R2) agent box on which i have installed Active Directory. I am now trying to create OUs in it.

```
[root@myhost] cat create_organizational_unit.pp
class infra::ad::create_organizational_unit (
    $ou_data = $infra::params::ou_data,
) inherits infra::params {
    each($ou_data) |$ou_name, $ou_dc_path| {
       windows_ad::organisationalunit { "$ou_name":
           ensure => present,
           path   => $ou_dc_path,
           ouName => $ou_name,
       }
    }
}

[root@myhost] cat params.pp
$ou_data = {
    'Support'       => 'DC=TEST,DC=COM',
    'DBA'           => 'DC=TEST,DC=COM',
    'SFTP'          => 'DC=TEST,DC=COM',
    'PROD'          => 'OU=SFTP,DC=TEST,DC=COM',
    'Users'         => 'OU=PROD,OU=SFTP,DC=TEST,DC=COM',
    'Groups'        => 'OU=PROD,OU=SFTP,DC=TEST,DC=COM',
},
```

Issue i am facing now is that when i apply the catalog by running `puppet agent -t` on agent, i see *either* of the following behaviour:

1) Either i have to run the above command multiple times because it doesn't apply the catalog in one go.

2) Irrespective of how many times i run the above command, it just doesn't apply the full catalog.

Why is it so? This is not the first time i have seen this. Although not frequent, it does happen at times.

UPDATE: Running in debug mode also did not provide anything useful. Tried running a powershell script for creating the same OU hierarchy and it works just fine. I am using [windows_ad](https://forge.puppet.com/jriviere/windows_ad) module. I see there is no active development on this module. So thought of trying [winad](https://forge.puppet.com/shoneslab/winad) which is active but when tried fetching catalog, i get the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while eval
uating a Resource Statement, Could not autoload puppet/type/winad_ou: no such file to load -- puppet/util/validator at /etc/puppetlabs/
code/environments/automation/modules/infra/manifests/ad/create_organizational_unit.pp:5:9 on node abc.temp.com","issue_kind":"RUN
TIME_ERROR"}
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
```

Puppet agent version:

```
C:\>puppet --version
4.5.2
```

Comment: Have you tried running with debug output on this node? I use the following command for maximum output. It should give you a good sense of the order things are being applied in and why something may not be being applied. `puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize --debug --verbose`

Comment: Please check UPDATE section in my post